# This almost periodic condition implies equicontinuity?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Let $X$ be a metrizable compact space and $T\colon X\to X$ a minimal homeomorphism, i.e.
$$ \mathrm{orb}(x) := \{T^kx:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
is dense in $X$ for every $x \in X$. Assume that the following condition is met:

- There exist $\varepsilon_n \to 0$ and $s_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(T^{s_n}x,x) < \varepsilon_n$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in X$.

This implies that $X$ is equicontinuous? When $X$ is a subshift it is easy to see that this is true (beacuse, then, every point is periodic), but for a general system I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Hi, Ia writing just to signal a little typo: perhaps it is minimal, not minim**i**al.

Comment: Here is a relevant statement: If $T$ is an isometry and $X$ is proper, then $X$ is compact --- it is simple, but not trivial; see  “On conditions under which...” by Aleksander Całka.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin you are right! In fact in every equicontinuous system this can happen. What about if this condition implies equicontinuity? I will edit the question.

Comment: This is called uniform topological rigidity if I recall correctly, and https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03366 should contain some info.

Comment: I think your specific question is answered by their statement that rigidity of minimal systems does not imply uniform rigidity, but I can't check now.

Comment: @VilleSalo My condition is equivalent to uniform rigidity, and in the arxiv article they say that there are uniformly rigid and weakly mixing actions. So, the answer to my question is negative. Thanks!

Comment: I checked now, and I think I was wrong: the statement that "rigidity of minimal systems does not imply uniform rigidity" does not solve your problem, exactly because you're already looking for uniform rigidity + extra properties. The main result of the paper also does not solve the problem, I think, because they don't construct minimal models (I haven't read the construction, but they don't seem to state it is minimal, and someone once asked me if it can be made minimal (I didn't know)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, such a homeomorphism is not necessary equicontinuous.

The existence of such examples on $X=\mathbb{T}^2$, i.e. the $2$-torus, can be shown as follows: let $\mathcal{O}$ be the $C^\infty$ closure of the set $\{h\circ R_\alpha\circ h^{-1} : h\in\mathrm{Diff}^\infty(\mathbb{T^2}),\ \alpha\in\mathbb{T}^2\}$, where $\mathbb{T}^2$ denotes the $2$-torus and $R_\alpha : \mathbb{T}^2\ni x\mapsto x+\alpha$.

Fathi and Herman showed in

*Fathi, Albert; Herman, Michael R.*, Existence de difféomorphismes minimaux, Astérisque 49(1977), 37-59 (1978). [ZBL0374.58010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0374.58010).

that there is residual set $C_0\subset \mathcal{O}$ such that every diffeomorphism of $C_0$ is minimal.

On the other hand, in

*Kocsard, Alejandro; Koropecki, Andrés*, [**A mixing-like property and inexistence of invariant foliations for minimal diffeomorphisms of the 2-torus**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-09-09903-1), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 137, No. 10, 3379-3386 (2009). [ZBL1179.37063](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1179.37063).

we proved the existence of a residual set $C_1\subset\mathcal{O}$ such that any $f\in C_1$ is weak-spreading, i.e. if $\tilde f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a lift of $f$, then for every non-empty open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, every $\epsilon>0$ and any $R>0$, there exist $n>0$ and a ball $B_R\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ of radius $R$ such that $\tilde f^n(U)$ is $\epsilon$-dense in $B_R$.  It is clear that every weak spreading homeomorphism is not equicontinuous.

Finally, one can show that rigid diffeomorphisms are generic in $\mathcal{O}$, i.e. there is residual set $C_2\subset\mathcal{O}$ such that for every $f\in C_2$ there is a sequence of natural numbers $n_j\to \infty$ so that $f^{n_j}\to id$ in the $C^0$ uniformly, when $j\to \infty$.

So, any diffeomorphism in $C_0\cap C_1\cap C_2$ is minimal and rigid, but not equicontinuous.

Comment: Thank you very much!